# Sum to infinity of trignometry inverse: $\sum_{r=1}^\infty\arctan \left(\frac{4}{r^2+3} \right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, trigonometry, closed-form

If we have to find the value of the following (1)
$$
\sum_{r=1}^\infty\arctan \left(\frac{4}{r^2+3} \right)
$$
I know that
$$
\arctan \left(\frac{4}{r^2+3} \right)=\arctan \left(\frac{r+1}2 \right)-\arctan \left(\frac{r-1}2  \right)
$$

I tried it lot and got a result but then stuck! (2)

(1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/26hA4.jpg
  (2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2vBb.jpg

Comment: Sorry due to low reputation , i cannot post image

Comment: Are you Ok with my edit? Let me know.

Comment: @OlivierOloa yes thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^\infty\arctan\left(\frac4{r^2+3}\right)
&=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\left[\arctan\left(\frac2{r-1}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac2{r+1}\right)\right]\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{r=1}^n\arctan\left(\frac2{r-1}\right)-\sum_{r=3}^{n+2}\arctan\left(\frac2{r-1}\right)\right]\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac\pi2+\arctan(2)-\arctan\left(\frac2n\right)-\arctan\left(\frac2{n+1}\right)\right]\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi2+\arctan(2)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 6):

One may observe that summing
$$
u_{r+1}-u_{r-1}
$$ may be simplified  as a telescoping sum:

> $$
> \sum_{r=1}^N\left(u_{r+1}-u_{r-1}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^N\left(u_{r+1}-u_{r}\right)+\sum_{r=1}^N\left(u_{r}-u_{r-1}\right)=u_{N+1}+u_N-u_1-u_0.
> $$

From the identity
$$
\arctan \left(\frac{4}{r^2+3} \right)=\arctan \left(\frac{r+1}2 \right)-\arctan \left(\frac{r-1}2  \right)
$$ by telescoping you then obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^N\arctan \left(\frac{4}{r^2+3} \right)&=\arctan \left(\frac{N+1}2 \right)+\arctan \left(\frac{N}2 \right)
\\\\&-\arctan \left(\frac12  \right)-\arctan \left(\frac{1-1}2  \right),
\end{align}
$$ giving, as $N \to \infty$ ,

> $$
> \sum_{r=1}^\infty\arctan \left(\frac{4}{r^2+3} \right)=2\arctan \left(\infty \right)-\arctan \left(\frac12 \right)=\frac{\pi}2+\arctan 2.
> $$

Comment: but how does other terms get cancelled

Comment: @user123733 Like this $(u_2-u_0)+(u_3-u_1)+(u_4-u_2)+\cdot+(u_N-u_{N-1})$, do you see the terms cancel?

Comment: @OlivierOloa are you sure? Shouldn't it be $\pi -\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$?

Comment: @OlivierOloa then one term will left

Comment: @OlivierOloa it should be +arctan 2

Comment: Numerically, the answer is $\frac\pi2+\arctan(2)=2.677945$

Comment: Now this looks correct. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{r=1}^N\arctan\left(\frac{r+1}2\right)-\sum_{r=1}^N\arctan\left(\frac{r-1}2\right)=\sum_{r=1}^N\arctan\left(\frac{r+1}2\right)-\sum_{r=-1}^{N-2}\arctan\left(\frac{r+1}2\right)$$
$$=\sum_{r=1}^N\arctan\left(\frac{r+1}2\right)-\sum_{r=1}^N\arctan\left(\frac{r+1}2\right)-\arctan\left(0\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{1}2\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{N}2\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{N+1}2\right)$$

Then let $N\rightarrow \infty$...

You then get $$\boxed {\pi -\arctan\left(\frac12\right)}$$

Comment: How r=-1 in your first step

Comment: @user123733  set for example $u+1=r-1$ then $u=r-2$ then for $r=1$ you have $u=-1$

Comment: But everyone is getting another result

Comment: @user123733 it is the same result...

Comment: There it is pi/2

Comment: @user123733 and here there is a minus... A few manipulations give it the same form. They have the exact same value

Comment: I am not talkng about mius . I am talking about the pi

Comment: Robjohn for example used the fact that for $x>0$ we have $\arctan(1/x) +\arctan(x)=\pi/2$. This gave him a result that LOOKS different, but is the exact same... The value is the same

Comment: @robjohn $$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \arctan(N/2)+\arctan((N+1)/2=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \arctan(N/2)+\arctan(N/2)=2\times  \pi/2$$

Comment: @GeorgSaliba: sorry, my mistake. You are correct. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

We already have plenty of slick answers through creative telescoping, so I will go for the overkill. 
By crude estimations we have $\sum_{r\geq 3}\frac{4}{r^2+3}\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$, hence:

$$ \sum_{r\geq 3}\arctan\left(\frac{4}{r^2+3}\right) = \text{Arg}\prod_{r\geq 3}\frac{r^2+3+4i}{r^2}\tag{1}=\text{Arg}\prod_{r\geq 3}\left(1+\frac{(2+i)^2}{r^2}\right)$$
but due to the Weierstrass product for the $\sinh$ function:
$$\prod_{r\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{(2+i)^2}{r^2}\right)=\frac{\sinh(2\pi+\pi i)}{\pi(2+i)}=-\frac{\sinh(2\pi)}{\pi(2+i)}\tag{2}$$
and that leads to:
$$ \sum_{r\geq 1}\arctan\left(\frac{4}{r^2+3}\right) = \color{red}{\pi-\arctan\frac{1}{2}}.\tag{3}$$